# What HTTP error should I return if the client accesses a URL through GET but should have used POST?

Tags: http

Say I have a URL `https://myapi.com/postatme` that is meant to receive data through `POST` but the user manually enters this URL into their browser and presses Enter. Should my server respond with `405 (Method Not Allowed)` or `400 (Bad request)`?

Comment: Does that endpoint also support GET? If not, 405.

Comment: Obviously a 405.

Comment: @jonrsharpe When the user GETs that endpoint, the server returns a JSON like so: `{"err":"GET not supported here"}`

Comment: Returning an error message seems a lot like not supporting that method, no? I generally just use https://www.codetinkerer.com/2015/12/04/choosing-an-http-status-code.html

Comment: Alright. I will use 405 then. Sometimes HTTP error descriptions can be a bit ambiguous. Cheers.